# Assigning variable with other variable in python

Tags: python

Hey guys am new to python development..I am studying python on my way

I have just tested a simple code which includes assigning two variables with single at one line

Here is my snippet:

```
name = 1
somevariable = "hellow am new to python"

print somevariable[name]
```

And i got an output "e".

I did not understand what it means. I just tried out a random example .Is it allowed to do like this in python .or is it with arrays. Please help me to find an appropriate answer. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIt

Can we store a variable information to other variable in python

For eg

```
name = 1
age = 2

string = "yeah am a man"

name[age] = stringname = 1
```

My qus is that can we store the value 1 to age ?..AM new to python ..Sorry for the bad question

Comment: You do not need that semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to read basic of python first, because from your snippet clearly says that you don't know what is mutable and immutable object in python.

And for your question,this `name[age] = stringname = 1` is not allowed.

First you will name Error for `age` after that you will get `int` object is not allowed for item assignment.

About [list](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm): 
About [Dictionary](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm):

Comment: yeah i know that ..but my question is not like that ..can we assign a value of varibale to other varibale in square brackt like i explained in my question ?

Comment: that you din't asked in your question, please update your question.

Comment: you got my question now ?

Comment: A string is immutable. While `variable[i] = 'x'` might be valid with a list you can't do this with a string. You'll find more basic info in the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).

Comment: Please read the basics of python first.

Comment: @Matthias so can you please explain in the terms of list ?...or just give me a link on how to do varibale[i] = x ..?..Is i aded to the list x here ?

Comment: updated a link in my answer please read about list and dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve, but it sounds a bit like you're trying to store multiple attributes (e.g name and age). If so, you could use a dict. e.g.

```
# initialise the dict
user = {}
# Add some data
user["name"] = "User"
user["age"] = 1
```

To retrieve the variables, just use e.g. `user["name"]`